# How to get a single value as a string from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am querying a single value from my data frame which seems to be 'dtype: object'. I simply want to print the value as it is with out printing the index or other information as well. How do I do this?

```
col_names = ['Host', 'Port']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)
df.loc[len(df)] = ['a', 'b']

t = df[df['Host'] == 'a']['Port']
print(t)
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
b

Comment: Try using `t = df[df['Host'] == 'a']['Port'][0]` or `t = df[df['Host'] == 'a']['Port'][1]`. I have a fuzzy memory of this working for me during debugging in the past.

Comment: Nice, t = df[df['Host'] == 'a']['Port'][1] worked

Comment: Using .loc df.loc[df['Host'] == 'a','Port'][0]

Comment: @OamarKanji, it should be simple `df[df['Host'] == 'a']['Port'][0]` or `print(df[df['Host'] == 'a']['Port'][0])

Comment: @OamarKanji Glad to have helped, I moved my comment to an answer

Comment: OP, Please read all the answers properly. The answer given by @PL200 is not completely correct because it will not work unless your index begins with 0. I have shown an example.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you can guarantee only one result is returned, use `loc` and call `item`:

```
>>> df.loc[df['Host'] == 'a', 'Port'].item()
'b'
```

Or, similarly,

```
>>> df.loc[df['Host'] == 'a', 'Port'].values[0]
'b'
```

...to get the *first* value (similarly, `.values[1]` for the second). Which is better than `df.loc[df['Host'] == 'a', 'Port'][0]` because, if your DataFrame looks like this,

```
  Host Port
1    a    b
```

Then "KeyError: 0" will be thrown—

```
df.loc[df['Host'] == 'a', 'Port'][0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
```

---

Alternatively, use `at`:

```
>>> df.at[df['Host'].eq('a').idxmax(), 'Port']
'b'
```

The drawback is that if 'a' doesn't exist, `idxmax` will return the first index (and return an incorrect result).

Comment: `FutureWarning: 'item' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version`

Comment: @rraadd88 Are you sure? The docs don't say that [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html)?

Comment: Yup, for some reason that warning do not exist any more. Strange.

Comment: or, you can use `df.Host.values`  to get the list with values of Host column, or `df.Host.values[0]` and  `df.Port.values[0]` to get  string values. Correct me if I wrong, it works for me

Answer (score 7):

```
t = df['Host'].values[0]
```

will give you the first value. If you need a string, just do:

```
t = str(df['Host'].values[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

it should work simply..

```
>>> df
  Host Port
0    a    b
>>> df[df['Host'] == 'a']['Port'][0]   # will choose the first index simply which is 'b'
'b'
```

OR, use with print which will strip off the surrounded single ticks.

```
>>> print(df[df['Host'] == 'a']['Port'][0])
b
```

This will easier because you have just choose the desired Index even if you have Multiple values across `Port` columns

**Example:**

```
>>> df
  Host Port
0    a    b
1    c    c
```

Looking for distinct `a` & `c` based on Index:

```
>>> df[df['Host'] == 'a']['Port'][0]
'b'
>>> df[df['Host'] == 'c']['Port'][1]
'c'
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, using [1] should work afterwards, to pull the variable you're looking for.

```
t = df[df['Host'] == 'a']['Port'][1]
```

Comment: As mentioned above, regardless of whether the correct value is at the 0th or 1st position, this will not work if the index is a RangeIndex starting from 0.