# Extracting numerical value with special characters from a string but removing other occurrences of those characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am using Python and pandas and have a DataFrame column
that contains a string. I want to keep the float number within the string and get rid of '-  .' at the end of the float (string).

So far I have been using a regular expression below to get rid of characters and brackets from the original string but it leaves '-' and '.' from the non-numeric part of the string in place.

Example input string :
`14,513.045Non-compliant with installation req.`

When I try to modify it this is what I get: 
`14,513.045-   .`     (example of positive number string)

I also want to be able to parse negative numbers, such as:
`-234.670`

The first `-` in the string is for negative float number. I would like to keep the first `-` and first `.` but get rid of the subsequent ones - the ones which do not belong to the number.

This is the code that I tried to use to achieve that:

```
dataframe3['single_chainage2'] = dataframe3['single_chainage'].str.replace(r"[a-zA-Z*()]",'')
```

But it leaves me with `14,513.045-   .`

I saw no way of doing the above using pandas alone and saw that regex was the recommended way.

Comment: Don't use a column name as if it is an attribute, always use it with square brackets indexing, as Python allows creation of attribute of an object even after the object is created and sometimes this may lend you in big trouble.

Comment: Thanks Ankit. I'll take that on board. I am fairly new to python

Answer (score 0):

You dont't need to `replace`, I think you can use `Series.str.extract` instead to get the string you need.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                     

In [2]: ser = pd.Series(["14,513.045Non-compliant with installation req.", "14,513.045- .", "-234.670"])                                                        

In [3]: pat = r'^(?P<num>-?(\d+,)*\d+(\.\d+)?)'

In [5]: ser.str.extract(pat)['num']                                                                                                                             
Out[5]: 
0    14,513.045
1    14,513.045
2      -234.670
Name: num, dtype: object
```

and a named group is needed in the regex pattern (`num` in this example) .

and if need to convert it to numeric dtype:

```
In [7]: ser.str.extract(pat)['num'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)                                                                                          
Out[7]: 
0    14513.045
1    14513.045
2     -234.670
Name: num, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks Woods. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing the characters that you don't want, just specify a pattern that you want to find and extract it. It should be much less error prone.
You want to extract a positive and negative number that can be floating point:

```
import re
number_match = re.search("[+-]?(\d+,?)*(\.\d+)?", 'Your string.')
number = number_match.group(0)
```

Testing the code above:

```
test_string_positive='14,513.045Non-compliant with installation req.'
test_string_negative='-234.670Non-compliant with installation req.'

In [1]: test=re.search("[+-]?(\d+,?)*(\.\d+)?",test_string_positive)

In [2]: test.group(0)
Out[2]: '14,513.045'

In [3]: test=re.search("[+-]?(\d+,?)*(\.\d+)?",test_string_negative)

In [4]: test.group(0)
Out[4]: '-234.670'
```

With this solution you don't want to do replace but rather just assign the value of the regex match.

```
number_match = re.search("[+-]?(\d+,?)*(\.\d+)?", <YOUR_STRING>)
number = number_match.group(0)
dataframe3['single_chainage2'] = number
```

I split that into 3 lines to show you how it logically follows. Hopefully, that makes sense.

You should substitute the value of `<YOUR_STRING>` with a string representation of data. As for how to get a string value out of a Pandas DataFrame, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255796/how-to-get-a-single-value-as-a-string-from-pandas-data-frame) might have some answers to that. I'm not sure about how your DataFrame actually looks but I guess something like `df['single_chainage'][0]` should work. Basically if you index in Pandas, it returns some Pandas specific info and if you want to retrieve just the string itself you have to specify that explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I tried the "[+-]?(\d+,?)*(\.\d+)?" in my dataframe3['single_chainage2'] = dataframe3.single_chainage.str.replace(r"[a-zA-Z*()]",'') command i.e dataframe3['single_chainage2'] = dataframe3.single_chainage.str.replace(r"[+-]?(\d+,?)*(\.\d+)?",'') but it was not allowing me to keep the float number, it deleted the float number and left everything else. Is there a was to keep the float number highlighted by your regex expression? Much thanks Dave

Comment: @daveb With the regex above you don't want to do replace but rather just assign it. I changed my answer to show how.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I tried the 3 lines of code as above but got the following error TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. I think it might be dataframe3['single_chainage'].

Comment: @daveb It just means you have to pass it as a string, I added a pointer to question that answers how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Sincerely appreciated. I'll give this a try

Comment: @daveb No problem at all, hope that works. If that did not work just let me know, hopefully we can resolve that. If it did I'd appreciate an upvote/accepted answer,