# python - get value by key from different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 'key' and 'value' columns, I would like to input a key and get output a value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'value': [2, 8, 10, 12]})

print(df)

key = 'B'
value = df[df['key'] == key]['value']
print(value)
```

Current output as below:

```
  key  value
0   A      2
1   B      8
2   C     10
3   D     12
1    8
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

How can I get the output value: 8 in this case since the key is 'B'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a value from a cell of a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729574/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-cell-of-a-dataframe)

Comment: `print(value.values[0])` will get you the answer.

Comment: btw, i did find another SO post that is similar.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255796/how-to-get-a-single-value-as-a-string-from-pandas-data-frame

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a single value as a string from pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255796/how-to-get-a-single-value-as-a-string-from-pandas-data-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use df.loc to get the specific value. You can give something like this.

```
df.loc[df.key == 'B','value'].item()
```

The output of this will be:

```
8
```

Or you can also give:

```
df.loc[df.key == 'B']['value'].item()
```

Or you can give:

```
df[df.key == 'B']['value'].iloc[0]
```

Or you can give:

```
df.loc[df.key == 'B', 'value'].values[0]
```

If you know for sure that you have only one item in the dataframe with key `'B'`, use `.item()`. If you are not sure, then I recommend that you use `.values[0]` as it will pick the first one from the result.

All of these will give you a value of `8`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It is pretty simple.

```
print(df['B'])
```

Comment: this wont work. You can't give `'B'` since it is not a column name

Comment: Not sure how this got an upvote. This is incorrect answer. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This should be good enough !!

```
df[df['key']=='B']['value'].iloc[0]
```